# Host the apple association file on IIS

Tags: ios, ios13, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to upload the apple association file into my IIS. And I'm using the following [Validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox) to validate that my association file is hosted correctly on my server.

I'm always getting the following error from the validator:

[image: Error getting from validator]

Even tough my association file is displayed correctly when entering the link.

I've tried the following:

1. Putting the association file at the root of my application
2. Putting the association file in the .well-known folder
3. Adding an `.htaccess` with the following inside of it:

   ```
   <Files "apple-app-site-association">
       ForceType 'application/json'
   </Files>
   ```

Is there something I need to add to `web.config`? How can we put the association file at the root of my IIS that contains more than one application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in `MIME Types` in IIS Manager, the problem was solved by adding a new `MIME Type` which tells the IIS to host the files with no extension as `JSON`

[image]